# Render or redirect from one page to another (i.e from login page to index page) that is separated in two different apps in Django

Tags: python, django

This what i'm getting:
[image: This what i'm getting]

I tried to render or redirect from one page to another (i.e from login page to index page) that is separated in two different apps (accounts and home) in Django but its redirecting to the same login page. I have to redirect to 'home/index.html' after login and have to authenticate the user details exists in the database. For registration also i'm getting the same issue, its storing the details but not redirecting to the index page after registration completes.

```
**Please some one help me fix this. Thanks in advance**

**`accounts - models.py'**
from django.db import models


class Registration(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

**'accounts - forms.py'**
from django import forms
from .models import *


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = ['email', 'password']


class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = ['email', 'password']


**'accounts - views.py'**
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import UserForm, LoginForm


def registration(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html', context)


def login_user(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password1=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                # return render(request, 'home/index.html')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request, 'home/index.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)


**'accounts - urls.py'**
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^registration/$', views.registration, name='registration'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login'),
]


**'home - views.py'**
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.shortcuts import render
from accounts.forms import UserForm


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, '', context)


**'home - urls.py'**
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]


**'project - urls.py'**
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^index/', include('home.urls')),
]


**'home/index.html'**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the home page</h1>
</body>
</html>

See the tree structure below for detailed information about the files,

project
   - project
        - init.py
        - settings.py
        - urls.py
        - wsgi.py
   - accounts
        - migrations
             - init.py
             - 0001_initial.py
        - init.py
        - admin.py
        - apps.py
        - forms.py
        - models.py
        - urls.py
        - test.py
        - views.py
   - home
        - init.py
        - admin.py
        - apps.py
        - models.py
        - urls.py
        - test.py
        - views.py
   - templates
        - accounts
             - login.html
             - registration.html
        - home
             - index.html
   - db.sqlite3
   - manage.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a couple things wrong. When you use `HttpResponseRedirect`, you should pass it the url of the page you want to redirect the user to, not the request and template like you would render.

Remember, you are not rendering or serving anything, but redirecting. So you only give the user a location to be sent to.

For example, your redirects should say

```
HttpResponseRedirect('/registration/')
```

and

```
HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

(as a sidenote I would actually recommend not using the urls directly [but rather reverse them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls), although for the time you should focus on getting your basics to work)

However as stated, this is not the only problem. In fact, your code isn't even reaching the `HttpResponseRedirect` calls (if it had you would have received an exception).

You are attempting to create users by using a model form based on your `Registration` model (bad idea). However, you are also trying to use Django's built in user backend (good idea). Simply put, when you save the registration form, it creates an instance of a `Registration` object, which you then attempt to treat as a Django user. Obviously this won't work, since it isn't a Django user at all, but an object with only an email and a plaintext password.

To be brief, I suggest scrapping the registration model (and related forms) altogether. Instead, for user authentication, you should use [Django's built-in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms), specifically the [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) (to be used on your registration page) and [`AuthenticationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) (to be used on your login page).

Consider [more reading](http://djangobook.com/) which will help walk you through these concepts, as they are important to do correctly.

---

Here is an example of a better approach, using a `OneToOneField` to link a profile model containing additional data to your user. This leaves the sensitive authentication information to be handled by django, so you can focus on your extra data.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='details')
    address = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    # No password/username/email/etc fields! See the user model
```

Then you need a form to get the extra data. Note! You will use two forms in the registration view, `UserCreationForm` and this one.

```
class UserDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetails
        fields = ('address', 'phone') # and any others
```

In your view, you will then instantiate both forms, one to create the user and one to create the details, and deal with them as appropriate.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    data = request.POST if request.POST else None

    user_form = UserCreationForm(data=data)
    details_form = UserDetailsForm(data=data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_valid = user_form.is_valid()
        details_valid = details_form.is_valid()

        if user_valid and details_valid:
            user = user_form.save()
            details = details_form.save(commit=False)
            details.user = user
            details.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return render(request, {'user_form': user_form, 'details_form': details_form})
```

You will then work with [users as described in Django's documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) Access the model class with `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, and authenticate as follows

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def login(request):
    data = request.POST if request.POST else None

    auth_form = AuthenticationForm(data=data, request=request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if auth_form.is_valid():
            # user authenticates successfully (note they are not logged in until we call login)
            # starts the authenticated session
            login(request, auth_form.user_cache)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    # etc...
```

Comment: But i want to create a custom registration form instead of using the UserCreationForm, because i want to add some fields like address, state, country, phone and etc. I'm new to django and i tried extending the registration form by inheriting UserCreationForm but i still not to save the extra fields i mentioned above in the users registry at admin site. Please show me some demo so that i can learn them with ease

Comment: I added an example describing the approach I suggest, you can extend it to get whatever additional features you want.